# Change this sentence into passive

Tags: passive-voice, active-vs-passive

How can this sentence be changed into passive voice:

> "My mother let me play today."

which one is correct:

1. I was let to play today by my mother.
2. I was let play today by my mother.

Comment: What is your question? Please review and make clear what you are asking?

Comment: I just realized that: I was let to play by my mother. could mean: my mother rented me out to play. Believe me, please, to let someone do something cannot be made passive.

Answer (score 3):

The technically correct answer is

> I was let to play by my mother

but *let* is not usually used this way and will sound awkward.  It sounds so awkward that you should consider it incorrect to use.

A native speaker will probably think you're trying to say *I was left to play by my mother.*

You should say *I was allowed to play by my mother* instead.

---

*Let out* doesn't have this problem, though.  But the meaning is slightly different.

> The dog was let out by someone.

Comment: "I was let to play by my mother" is technically correct? It is completely wrong. The technically correct form would be: "I was allowed to play by my mother." or: "My mother let me play".

Comment: It's "right" if you strictly follow syntax/grammar rules (*let* has same forms in all tenses including past participle) - and I'm pretty sure in passive voice you have to explicitly specify "to" for any infinitival complement - but you are right in that no one says that and it will be really jarring to hear/say.

Answer (score 1):

"My mother let me play today".

There is no passive here given as "was let". The verb **allow** must be used to give a passive meaning. let means allow. Please note: My mother allowed me to play today.

"I was allowed to play by my mother today".

The only passive use is when let means let out or rent, as is:

- Who let the dogs out? [like the song]
- The dogs were let out by me.
- Who let (out) this apartment?
- This apartment was let out by an agent.